# Third-party library in Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to use a pickadate.js libary in my project.

What I've tried so far...

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        formatSubmit: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        hiddenName: true
    });
  }
```

Gets the following error:

> $(...).pickadate is not a function

I really don't want to write a td.ts for anything in my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My Angular2 App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/pickadate/lib/themes/default.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/assets/main.css">
  <!-- endinject -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"> </script>
    <!-- inject:js -->
  <script src="/node_modules/pickadate/lib/legacy.js"></script>
  <script src="/node_modules/pickadate/lib/picker.time.js"></script>
  <script src="/node_modules/pickadate/lib/picker.date.js"></script>
  <script src="/node_modules/pickadate/lib/picker.js"></script>
  <!-- endinject -->

</head>
<body>

...
```

Comment: Where did you add the jQuery import? Script tags in templates are dropped. There are also a few questions about datepicker in Angular2 already. Did you check if they provide the info you need?

Comment: It looks like you haven't added 'pickadate' library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have included the [TSD](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/raw/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts) (right click, save as...) for jQuery into your App Component:

```
/// <reference path="../path/to/jquery.d.ts" />
```

Then also download this [typing](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/raw/ffceea9dd124d277c4597c7bd12930666ec074c5/pickadate/pickadate.d.ts) and import as so:

```
/// <reference path="../path/to/pickadate.d.ts" />
```

Lastly, make sure jQuery and PickADate are imported into your HTML. If everything is right, your code should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add the library script tag inside a components template. `<script>` tags in Angular2 templates are dropped.

Comment: ok the fault was that i called the picker not after my jquery.js thx